# How to DELETE all entries that aren't in a time range in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table for connections that have the following structure:

```
->ip
->first (datetime of the entry creation)
->last (datetime of last update to the entry)
```

Datetimes are in the format `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

Now I want to delete every entry that have `last - first > 5 minutes` as `true`. How can I do that in the SQL query?

Comment: Sure is timestamp and not datetime? I don't see the problem otherwise :)

Comment: I forget to mention that 5 is in minutes.

Comment: I'm wrong again, it's a datetime`Y-m-d H:i:s`

Comment: I told you :) see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

```
DELETE FROM `tableName` WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,`first`,`last`) > 5
```

Answer (score 3):

simply add it as where condition

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `last` - `first` > 5;
```

Comment: Please look at my edited question, I was wrong saying timestamp, now I corrected my question.